# Update global variable from jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, jquery-ui

Firstly, please note I am new to jQuery and have limited js experience, so this may be a silly question, but I have no one to ask for help.

I have a jQuery range slider which provides two year values. I have successfully created a variable which contains both the minimum and maximum year. 
I am unsure how to update the min/max year variables after the user interacts with the range slider. 
I need the the min/max year values as variables to use as a filter for a map/geojson query.

I have tried to declare the variable equal to ui.value(0) and ui.value[0], but that is as far as I have gotten. (example:   `yrmin = ui.value[0];` )
The only thing I know for certain is that I don't know enough. Any direction, comments, suggestions, or links to related exercises/ problems etc would be so incredibly helpful.

```
var yrmin = ''; 
var yrmax = ''; 
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
                range: true,
                min: 1900,
                max: 2020,
                values: [ 1945, 1995 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#amount" ).val( " " + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( " " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
    yrmin = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
    yrmax = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
});
```

When I use the the  `yrmin = ui.value(0);` the console logs a ui not defined error..

Comment: try it using dummy data insade your jquery event function. so you can check where exactly the problem maybe not in variable set. but your slider data has problem

Comment: Global variables should be avoided where possible. A better idea would be to read the values from the range slider when you need to use them in your map.

Comment: `ui.value(0)` is calling `value` (note missing `s`) as a function when you want `ui.values[0]`

Comment: Why bother with the variables at all? Just access the value of the slider when you need the data. There's less coding and you're sure to get the most up to date values when you need them.

Comment: Thanks for such prompt and valuable input. I originally thought that would be the best way to go, as retrieving the value as needed would do the same as retrieving a variable set by the slider's value.

Comment: I think I'm just a little stuck on how to retrieve the value from a jquery slider as it changes based upon user selection. What would be the best way to do this? Is there any [free, online] reading material that I could reference to better understand how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (window), but I do recommend to avoid the global approach as much as you can

> window scope

```
window.yrmin = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
window.yrmax = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);
```